# Counting bytes transferred from HTTP logs

Tags: python, http, parsing, https

I am new at python and I need to parse status codes. I have a task to parse the HTTP log file:

- Group the logged requests by IP address or HTTP status code
  (selected by the user).
- Calculate one of the following (selected by the user) for each group:

  1. Request count
  2. Request count percentage of all logged requests
  3. The total number of bytes transferred.

I have made the calculation of requests and percentages. Now I do not know how to count the transferred bytes (3rd task).

The example of a log file (bytes are shown here after status code: 6146, 52315, 12251, 54662):

```
93.114.45.13 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:17 +0000] "GET /images/jordan-80.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6146 "http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/dynamic-dns-with-dhcp/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
93.114.45.13 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:21 +0000] "GET /images/web/2009/banner.png HTTP/1.1" 200 52315 "http://www.semicomplete.com/style2.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
66.249.73.135 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:40 +0000] "GET /blog/tags/ipv6 HTTP/1.1" 200 12251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:25 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/elasticsearch.png HTTP/1.1" 200 8026 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:59 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/logstashbook.png HTTP/1.1" 200 54662 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
```

My code :

```
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter

def getBytes(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            newlist=line.split(" ")    
            print(newlist[0]+" "+newlist[9])

def countIp(filename):
    print ("hey")
    myregex = r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
    with open(filename) as f:
        log = f.read()
        my_iplist = re.findall(myregex,log)
        ipcount = Counter(my_iplist)
        s = sum(ipcount.values())
        for k,v in ipcount.items():        
            pct = v * 100.0 / s   
            print("IP Address " + "=> " + str(k) + " " + "Count "  + "=> " + str(v) + " Percentage " +"=> "+ str(pct) +"%")

def countStatusCode(filename):
    print ("hey")
    myregex = r'\b[2-5]\d\d\s'
    with open(filename) as f:
        log = f.read()
        my_iplist = re.findall(myregex,log)
        ipcount = Counter(my_iplist)
        s = sum(ipcount.values())
        for k,v in ipcount.items():        
            pct = v * 100.0 / s   
            print("IP Address " + "=> " + str(k) + " " + "Count "  + "=> " + str(v) + " Percentage " +"=> "+ str(pct) +"%")

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    filename=sys.argv[1]
    val = input("Enter your choice (ip or status code): ") 
    if val in ["ip","IP","Ip","iP"]:    
        countIp(filename)
    elif val in ["statusCode","code","sc","Status Code","status"]:
        countStatusCode(filename)
```

Comment: ignore getBytes method

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @NedasJankauskas: rather than ask us to ignore something, *just remove it from your question*.

Comment: @PedroLobito my question is to count transferred bytes. For example, by now my output is:  Status code => 216  Count => 23 Percentage => 42.592592592592595% But, I want it to be Status code => 216  Count => 23 Percentage => 42.592592592592595% Bytes transferred => 'Calculated number'

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Extracting the number of bytes from each log entry? Is each log entry on a single line? I think your status code pattern is matching things that you didn't intend to match.

Answer (score 0):

To get number of bytes transfered from your logfile:

```
def getBytes(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            regex = r'\/.+?\sHTTP\/1\..\"\s.{3}\s(.+?)\s'
            bytesCount = re.search(regex, line)[1]
            print("Bytes transfered: "+bytesCount)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this was not what I asked for. I want that bytes would be calculated for specific IP address or HTTP status code ( Like a group by function in sql) . For example, in this case, the output would be: Status code => 200 Count => 23 Percentage => 42.592592592592595% Bytes transferred => 'Calculated number'

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using multiple regular expressions making multiple passes through the log, this solution uses one regular expression to pull out all the relevant values in one pass.

Function `process_log` is passed the text of the log as a single string. In the following demo program, a test string is used. An actual implementation would call this function with the results of reading the actual log file.

To keep track of IP addresses/status pairs, a `defaultdict` using a `list` as the default_factory is used. The number of items in the list counts the number of times the IP address/status combination has been seen and each list item is the number of bytes transferred for that HTTP request. For example, an key/value pair of the `ip_status` dictionary might be:

```
key: ('123.12.11.9', '200')  value: [6213, 9876, 376]
```

The interpretation of the above is that there were 3 instances of status code '200' for ip address '123.12.11.9' discovered. The bytes transferred for these 3 instances were 6213, 9876 and 376.

Explanation of the regex:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) - - .*?HTTP/1.1" (\d+) (\d+)
```

1. `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) - -` This is essentially the regex used by the OP to recognize an IP address so it shouldn't require much of an explanation. I have followed it with `- -` to provide additional following context just in case there are other instances of similar looking strings. The IP address is captured in Capture Group 1.
2. `.*?` This will match non-greedily 0 or more non-newline characters until the following.
3. `HTTP/1.1"` Matches the string `HTTP/1.1"` to provide left-hand context for the following.
4. `(\d+)` Matches one or more digit in Capture Group 2 (the status).
5. Matches a single space.
6. `(\d+)` Matches one or more digit in Capture Group 3 (the transferred bytes).

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LVQCTI/1)

In other words, I just want to make sure I am picking up the right fields from the right place by matching what I expect to find *next* to the fields I am looking for. When your regex returns multiple groups, `finditer` is often more convenient then `findall`. `finditer` returns an iterator yielding a match object for each iteration. I have added code to produce statistics for *both* **ip/status code/transferred bytes** and just **status code**. You need only one or another depending on what the user wants.

The code:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

def process_log(log):
    ip_counter = defaultdict(list)
    status_counter = defaultdict(int)
    total_count = 0
    for m in re.finditer(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) - - .*?HTTP/1.1" (\d+) (\d+)', log):
        total_count += 1
        ip = m[1]
        status = m[2]
        bytes = int(m[3])
        ip_counter[(ip, status)].append(bytes)
        status_counter[status] += 1
    for k, v in ip_counter.items():
        count = len(v)
        percentage = count/total_count
        total_bytes = sum(v)
        ip = k[0]
        status = k[1]
        print(f"IP Address => {ip}, status => {status}, Count => {count}, Percentage => {percentage}, Total Bytes Transferred => {total_bytes}")
    for k, v in status_counter.items():
        count = v
        percentage = count/total_count
        print(f"Status Code => {k}, Percentage => {percentage}")




log = """93.114.45.13 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:17 +0000] "GET /images/jordan-80.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6146 "http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/dynamic-dns-with-dhcp/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
93.114.45.13 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:21 +0000] "GET /images/web/2009/banner.png HTTP/1.1" 200 52315 "http://www.semicomplete.com/style2.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
66.249.73.135 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:40 +0000] "GET /blog/tags/ipv6 HTTP/1.1" 200 12251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:25 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/elasticsearch.png HTTP/1.1" 200 8026 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:59 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/logstashbook.png HTTP/1.1" 200 54662 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
"""

process_log(log)
```

Prints:

```
IP Address => 93.114.45.13, status => 200, Count => 2, Percentage => 0.4, Total Bytes Transferred => 58461
IP Address => 66.249.73.135, status => 200, Count => 1, Percentage => 0.2, Total Bytes Transferred => 12251
IP Address => 83.149.9.216, status => 200, Count => 2, Percentage => 0.4, Total Bytes Transferred => 62688
Status Code => 200, Percentage => 1.0
```

[See Python Demo](https://ideone.com/RAlVo3)

Comment: Thank u a lot, but could you please explain your redex?

Comment: I have added some explanations.